# Android develop: GridView in ListView, the focus issues

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I have a gridView in the ListView, and every Listview item has its own gridview, i don't want the gridview has the focus, such as when I click the gridview, I can click into the listitem(through onitemclicklistener).

I have set the gridview:

```
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

and list item set:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

but it is not working.
here is the listitem.xml：

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#77FFFFFF"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="167dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="7dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/offername"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="name"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/offerdate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="date"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/share"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/share_black" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/offercontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:text="content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/imagegrid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#DD444444"
            android:columnWidth="50dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="4"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
        </GridView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/black_gray" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="@string/relativeproduct"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/productquantity"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/product_image" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

put this attribute to adapter layout xml

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Comment: Your mean in the item layout? I have put this code in the xml. But it doesn't work. Is there anything wrong? Thank you.